# Applications does not take parameters with scala.js or type

Tags: scala, d3.js, scala.js

I am currently developing a DSL on scala-d3-js and I am trying to use currying and type definition to avoid having multiple maps in the following code:

```
trait HistogramInterface {

  import constants.Distributions._
  type Fun = ((Double) => js.Function0[Double]) | ((Double) => ((Double) => js.Function0[Double]))
  val DistributionMap: Map[String, Fun] = Map(
    Bates -> ((count: Double) => d3.random.bates(count)),
    Normal -> ((mean: Double) => (deviation: Double) => d3.random.normal(mean, deviation)),
    LogNormal -> ((mean: Double) => (deviation: Double) => d3.random.logNormal(mean, deviation)),
    IrwinHall -> ((count: Double) => d3.random.irwinHall(count))
  )


  implicit object Histogram extends HistogramInterface {
    def apply(nbBars: Int, dataArg: Seq[Double]): Selection[EventTarget] = createHistogram(nbBars, dataArg)
  }

  implicit object DistributionHistogram extends HistogramInterface {
    def apply(nbBars: Int, token: String, args: Double*): Selection[EventTarget] = {
      val DistributionFun = DistributionMap(token)(args(0)) // application does not take parameters
      val values = token match {
        case Bates => d3.range(1000).map(_ => DistributionFun.apply())
        case Normal => d3.range(1000).map(_ => DistributionFun.apply())
      }
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

With this code, I am getting "Application does not take parameters" when assigning the constant `DistributionFun`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your types, `DistributionMap(token)` is a `Fun`, which you defined as a or type:

```
  type Fun =
    ((Double) => js.Function0[Double]) |
    ((Double) => ((Double) => js.Function0[Double]))
```

I don't think you can treat a union type as a function type this way. Even if you could, the result type would be `js.Function0[Double]) | ((Double) => js.Function0[Double]))`, which means you wouldn't be able to call `.apply()` with no arguments the way you do just after.

Comment: Thank you, 

That is what I was worried about. I will define another Map to handle the cases with two arguments functions.